# Using GEOMTRANSFORM twice on class in MapServer?

Tags: symbology, mapserver, coordinate-system

I want to know if and how it is possible to use GEOTRANSFORM two times on a class.
1. Creating a bounding box "bbox" of an object
2. Getting the "centroid" of that bounding box to display a vector symbol

Some of the documentation for MapServer GEOTRANSFORM is listed [here](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/geomtransform.html#expressions-and-advanced-transformations-layer-and-class-style), but i haven't been able to put the two functions together.

Maybe I should use this example `GEOMTRANSFORM (simplify(buffer([shape], 20),10))` and translate it into something like `GEOMTRANSFORM (centroid(GEOMTRANSFORM([bbox])))` . I have tried many combinations but so far none have worked. The layer settings in which I want to implement the transformation looks something like this:

```
LAYER
 GROUP "23Vandforsyning"
 NAME "Ventiler"
 TYPE LINE
 STATUS OFF
 CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
 CONNECTION "DanVand\DVG_Ventil.tab"
 MINSCALEDENOM 0
 MAXSCALEDENOM 3000
 FILTER (("[Status]" != "Ikke i brug") AND ("[Status]" != "Sløjfet") AND ("   [Status]" != "Planlagt"))

CLASS
    EXPRESSION ("[KompFunktion]" == "Stophane")
    STYLE
        GEOMTRANSFORM "centroid"
        ANGLE [VinkelSymbol]
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        SYMBOL 'Firkant_m_kryds' 
        SIZE 6
        MINSIZE 6
        MAXSIZE 6
    END
END
```

END

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one GEOMTRANSFORM. Allowing multiple GEOMTRANSFORMs should be possible, but requires changes to the codebase.

Comment: So, I pressume that changes to the codebase is something that requires a lot of work and expertise?